# is it possible to get python to write text in another program

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech, python-3.4

hi I made a text to speech app with a vbs script where I type the text and it will say what ever I typed.

I want to connect it to my python app where a user types tts 'text'
it with say the text in the apostrophes
here's a example I if I type

```
tts 'text'
```

is that possible? if it is possible how do you do it?

Comment: How do you run a vbs script at a terminal?

Comment: Telling us what interface you use for your text-to-speech script may be useful.

Comment: @CamCK can you write your script so that typing `tts.vbs hello` will say “hello”? Then it will become very easy to run it using python.

Comment: @CamCk for example, running another python program from within python is a simple matter of writing `os.system('python C:/Code/test.py')`

Comment: I can't write tts.vbs hello or tts.vbs 'hello'

Comment: the os.system command I know infact most of my python script uses the os.system command

Comment: @CamCK what I mean is that, when you run your vbs program, it takes the input from user? Via standard input?

Comment: no it doesn't it has a text box in it and then when I enter the text and press Enter it says the text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81302/discussion-between-rishav-kundu-and-cam-ck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it me and Rishav Kundu were in a chat room talking about and he give me the answer

the vbs script had this code

```
Dim msg, sapi
 msg=InputBox("Enter your text for text to speech")
 Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
 sapi.Speak msg
```

changed it to this

```
Dim sapi
Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")

Set args = Wscript.Arguments
For Each arg In args
  sapi.Speak arg
Next
```

then in the python script I typed in this

```
from os import system
st = input().strip()
if st.index('tts') == 0:
        say = st[st.index("'"):]
        say = say.replace("'","")
        cmd = 'CSCRIPT <enter path to script here, forward slashes> '+ say
        system(cmd)
```